# add a column to a mysql query from other subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table `user(id,name)` and a table `payments(date,amount,user_id)`

I need a query to display for each user the total sum of payments and the payments in last month.

```
User - totalpayments - monthlypayments
```

something like this

1. `SELECT id, name from user;`
2. `SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM payments WHERE user_id=user.id;`
3. `SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM payments WHERE user_id=user.id AND (data<=$timestamptoday AND data>=$timestamp1stday)`

is it possible to do that without doing many queries?

Comment: Sub queries and JOIN functions are your best help here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: Why are you doing COUNT(Amount)? I guess its SUM(Amount)? Also, you can use Group By to accomplish what you are looking for

Comment: yes it was a typing mistake, I meant the sum

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do it within one query.

```
SELECT
    u.ID,
    u.Name,
    SUM(p.amount),
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN p.date <= '2013-02-01' AND p.date >= '2013-01-01' THEN p.amount
          ELSE 0
        END)
FROM
    Users u
JOIN
    Payments p ON u.ID = p.UserID
GROUP BY
    u.ID,
    u.Name
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58142/8)

Comment: wow I'll take a while to understand the query, but yes that's exactly the result I need. Thanks

Comment: This is how I would do the job too, except I would probably use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: how do you do order by of p.amount?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can do this as a single query:

```
SELECT    user.name, SUM(amount) AS totalpayments, SUM(IF(date <= '$enddate' AND date >= '$startdate'),amount,0) AS monthlypayments
FROM      user LEFT JOIN payments ON user.id = payments.user_id
GROUP BY  user.id
ORDER BY  user.name ASC
```

Note that I'm using `SUM` rather than `COUNT` on the assumption that you're looking for the total amounts of the payments, rather than the number of payments there were.

Comment: p.s. what is the '0'? written as last parameter in the 2nd SUM function?

Comment: What that part is doing is saying "if we're within the right date, add the amount. Otherwise, add 0." It's just an if/else statement to make sure you're only adding what needs to be added.